# Need query to pull data form below mentioned tables

Tags: sql

Table1:
ID,
Job number

Table1products:
FKTable1ID,
FKProductID

Table2:
ID,
Inv number

Table2products:
FKTable2ID,
FKProductID

Product:
ID,
ProductName,
ProductCode

Need to pull job number, Inv number form table1 and table2 and product name and code form the common table Product.

Can someone please help me with the query. Thanks

Comment: Post what you have so far. Do you need to join them on IDs?...

Answer (score 0):

`Select table1.jobNumber, table2.invNumber from table1, table2`

`Select ProductName, ProductCode from Product`

These are pretty close to what you want...